Topic for undergraduate thesis
I'm an undergraduate student in my final year studying applied mathematics. To graduate, I need to present a thesis, and I'm considering using Lean and first-order predicate logic for my thesis.
My approach is as follows:

Use Lean to support the development of proofs and the verification
of properties in first-order predicate logic.

Present the
mathematical background of Lean.

Formalize a well-known theorem or the properties of first-order predicate logic in Lean, including their mathematical counterparts, to demonstrate Lean's capabilities.

As an application, verify the correctness of an algorithm.


Currently, I'm struggling with points 3 and 4. What would you suggest? The thesis should be completed within a maximum of 6 months, so I'm looking to avoid anything too complex. Thanks for your comments!

This is probably a question for best posed to your thesis advisor, but I would recommend proving the completeness of first-order logic. You could also do something involving proof calculi for first-order logic, like "A formula is provable in natural deduction iff it is provable in a Hilbert system iff it is provable in sequent calculus", or whatever.

I agree with Alex, why don't you ask your academic advisor about your thesis topic? We don't know your mathematical background in detail, and your proficiency in Lean (or other proof assistants) either.

This sort of thing needs to be decided together with your advisor. As to @AlexNelson's suggestion, if you have not got much experience with formalization, you could consider scaling it down to propositional calculus. Start with proving that a propositional formula is classically provable if, and only if, it is valid under every assignment of variables to values $\bot$ and $\top$ (also known as "truth tables"). First-order logic adds considerable complexity, as you have to deal with bound variables.

You profile says you're in applied math, so how about this:

Define bipartite graphs as those that have a vertex 2-coloring.
Prove that a graph is not bipartite if it has an odd closed walk (a self-intersecting cycle of odd length).
Implement a dept-first-search algorithm that looks for a 2-coloring of a graph, and prove that it it works correctly.

The plan is easy to extend, as there are dozens of theorems and algorithms on graphs.
At my university this would be good enough for an undergraduate thesis (after 3 years of study), but a bit thin for a master's thesis (after 3 + 2 years of study).

This is a great project. From what I have seen, formalizing DFS is quite nontrivial.

As others have said, your advisor is the best person to discuss this with.
Having said that, I think another good place to go is the Lean Zulip.  There you can have a back-and-forth discussion (not easy on this site) on possible topics.  Folks may have an idea that is especially suited for your interests and background.  If you post there, I recommend posting in the #new-members channel, introducing yourself and your background, and referencing this post so that you avoid too much cross-posting duplicate conversation.
Finally, sometimes it can be motivating to contribute to the larger common code bases.  Mathlib (Lean's main mathematics library) maintains some lists of possible projects to work on.  (Note, the lists are called "undergraduate" because they cover undergraduate mathematics, not necessarily because they are good undergraduate projects, but they are a good place to look for ideas:

Undergrad TODO trivial targets
Undergrad low hanging fruits

Over the years, the lists have gotten smaller, but you can look at them to see if anything catches your fancy.  (I would still ask on Zulip to make sure others haven't done it and forgot to cross it off the list.)  Also, there is nothing on there right now for logic or program verification.  I know there are lots of low-hanging verification needs in Lean's standard library Std (see the Contributing section).  Also, as for logic, there is a bunch of logic already in Mathlib under Logic, ModelTheory, and SetTheory.  There also are other projects like a recent proof of Godel's first incompleteness theorem which is slowly getting ported to Mathlib.  Maybe there is a way to help out with that as well.
